# cannot connect to google cloud compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have select allow http traffic when I create the instance and allow the tcp:80 traffice in VPC network setting, I also enabled port 80 in iptables, however I still cannot use netcat to connect to the 80 port, it's always "Connection refused". Anyone knows how to make it? Here is what my VPC setting looks like:
[My VPC setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZcAp.png), and my iptables looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DmgJ.png)

Thanks!

---

Update:
Sorry, my bad. I found I need to install Apache first then nc can find the 80 port opened.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing jumps out as being wrong with your FW ACLs. I'm not familiar with google cloud compute but things I'd try :

Are you definitely listening on port 80? - confirm with 'net stat -anp | grep 80'

Can you connect to port 80 locally on the server? - confirm with 'telnet PUBLICIP 80'

Suppose it's always possible it's a routing issue if you have multiple interfaces, make sure the default gateway is out the front end gateway - 'route -n'

The connection refused suggests its a FW somewhere dropping the connection or its not making it to a HTTP serve